# Remove Duplicate for query in sql

Tags: sql, duplicates

Input

```
source Destination distance
Mumbai Pune    150
Pune   Mumbai  150
Delhi  Agra    2000
```

here row1 and row2 are duplicate. how do i remove duplicate and load in one table

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: What does "remove duplicates" mean for you? Do you want to select a pair only once or do you want to remove records from your table? If the latter: do you even want to avoid future duplicates by a database constraint?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `CASE` expression to impose an order on the source and destination columns, effectively performing a sort on those columns. For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN source <= destination THEN source ELSE destination END AS source,
    CASE WHEN source <= destination THEN destination ELSE source END AS destination,
    distance
FROM distances
```

Note that this will reorder the columns in rows that have destination < source, e.g. a single row `bbb|aaa|1234` would be selected as `aaa|bbb|1234`. That shouldn't be a problem since the order of the first two columns is apparently insignificant.

To load into a new table you might be able to use the non-standard `SELECT (...) INTO new_table` SQL query. Not all database engines support it, so it depends on your particular product.

Comment: `select .. into new_table` is non-standard SQL. You should mention to which DBMS product your answer applies

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks. Yes, I know, for example SQLite doesn't support it. It would be impossible to list all that do, so I have edited. What about the use of `CASE` to solve this problem? That is standard SQL. Is there a problem with it? Is there a better way?

Comment: Your two case statements are for the same condition.

Comment: @HLGEM: yes, the two case conditions are the same; I think they should be, although you could invert one and also swap the corresponding actions. Each is selecting one of the columns so that the alphabetically lowest one is in the first column in the result set. Seems to work. Do you have another solution?